# One timezone in Angular 2+ without pipes

Tags: angular

In our project we deploy an angular 5 project in a docker container with httpd. When debugging locally in VsCode in Windows10 we see the time displayed correctly using the correct NL timezone (GMT+1). When deploying in our Linux hosted docker instance, we see the time as UTC (because of the default setting is UTC for Linux).

I want to force the timezone to be a Dutch timezone (CEST).
Is there a way to format a Date instance in Angular 2+ without using a pipe ?

I want one place to register the timezone for each Date instance in a view in Angular 2+.

Comment: This isn't a job for Angular or native Date. Angular isn't responsible for date formatting. This can be achieved with a pipe or else. Did you consider Moment? You likely should. It depends on the case if its timezone features are enough for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using a custom pipe (I couldn't find another way) and Moment JS and place it in the views where I need hour formatting. The code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({name: 'dutchDateFormat'})
export class DutchDateFormat implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: Date | string, format: string) {
    return this.convertToDutchDateFormat(input, format);
  }

  private convertToDutchDateFormat(inputDate: Date | string, format: string) : string {
    let isString = typeof inputDate === 'string';

    let date : Date;

    if (true === isString) {
        date = moment(inputDate as string).toDate();
    } else {
        date = inputDate as Date;
    }

    let localTimeString = date.toLocaleTimeString("nl-NL", { timeZone: 'Europe/Amsterdam'});
    let localDateTime = moment(localTimeString, 'hh:mm:ss');

    return moment(localDateTime).format(format);
  }
}
```

In your view format it like you want to:

```
| dutchDateFormat:'HH:mm'
```

Comment: Is it `nsDutchDateFormat` or `DutchDateFormat`? You said you did not want pipes…

Comment: It should be dutchDateFormat, was a typo